# python, dictionary and if statements

Tags: python

i have this code for renaming some files but when its the case that there are more than one file with the same name; the 'else' part doesn't even return the hello world

TArchivo is the extention of the file: like ',jpg' and Numero is the number of strings that it will take from the name
example:

Onthedirectory: 'name.txt'

def remove(3,'.txt')

onthedirectory: 'e.txt'

`import os
def remove(Numero,TArchivo):
    n = 0
    for fn in os.listdir("."):
        if fn[-4:] == TArchivo:
            if len(fn) > Numero:
                nombre = fn[Numero:-4:]
                nn = ''
                nn = nombre + TArchivo
                if nn not in os.listdir('.'):
                    os.rename(fn,nn)
                else:
                    print 'hello world'
                    n = n + 1
                    nombre = fn[Numero:-4] + str(n)
                    nn = nombre + TArchivo
                    os.rename(fn,nn)
return`

i get this error: 
WindowsError: [Error 183] Unable to create a file that already exists'

what i was trying to do with the n variable was that when there was a file with the same name in the directory it would add a number to the new name and then rename it like that

Comment: `print hello world` or `print 'hello world'`? What's the error that you're getting? What's `TArchivo` or `Numero`?

Comment: I imagine TArchivo is a 4 symbol long suffix such as `.txt`.

Comment: `fn[Numero:-4:]` won't do that for you. Try:
`>>> "somefilenamelongerthanten.txt"[10:-4:]`
and you will get: `'melongerthanten'`
It will start at #10 if you are lucky and the name has >14 chars. You may be in a situation where you get nothing e.g. with `"thirteen.txt"[10:-4:]`

Comment: you should use the interpreter, run your commands one by one and see what each one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very anti-stackoverflow-style question. That's why everybody react to it like this. The tradition is that you have to learn the core of the subject (do your homework so to say) and ask some constructive questions, not questions like "I have a problem -- do it for me".

Probably the question will be closed.
Nevertheless I would suggest you two things.
First -- take one of those great online courses on Python available from Coursera. Some links: the pair of [0](https://www.coursera.org/course/programming1) and [1](https://www.coursera.org/course/programming2), also [2](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python), [3](https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython1).

Your program does a simple procedure and nevertheless -- yet it is hard to read and understand.
Some simple corrections would make it much better, clearer and easier to understand.

For instance:

```
if fn[-4:] == TArchivo:
    if len(fn) > Numero:
```

should be

```
if fn[-4:] == TArchivo and len(fn) > Numero:
```

`nombre = fn[Numero:-4:]` does not need the second colon, it is the same as `nombre = fn[Numero:-4]`, `nn = ''` is not needed at all -- in Python you don't need to declare stuff upfront, you could write just:

```
nn = fn[Numero:-4] + TArchivo
```

and `str((str(n)))` -- ?!! It is just `str(n)`.

Second, the issue noticed by rudolfovic is quite correct. You should test for `if len(fn) > Numero + 4` to take into account the extension.
And also, collisions can still happen with the method you apply. Consider having files aaabcd.txt, aaabcd.txt, aaabcd1.txt. And you cut off 3 first characters.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my comment below your post: your error may be due to the problems with your substring logic. You have to say exactly what you are trying to do to let anyone see where you went wrong.